# Burndown chart TFS not displaying remaining work correctly

Tags: tfs

I have just created a SCRUM project inside TFS, created a new sprint and assigned the proper tasks to it.The problem that I have is with the burndown charts' Remaining Work.
I mention that the sprint started today 31/10/2016 and it will finish sunday, 6/11/2016.

This is the picture that shows it.

[image]

Can someone please explain why the chart starts from 60 as remaining hours instead of 80? The sprint just started 40 min ago.

Comment: In my case, this was related to the Feature status not being set to "Active"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both 60 and 80 is **not on behalf of hours** which means **team's total capacity at the start of the sprint.**

[image]

> - *(1) Team's total capacity at the start of the sprint*
> - *(2) 0 Remaining Work at the end of the sprint.*

---

**Update**

This is a normal phenomenon. For the remaining work, it will reduce the first working day's capacity.

If your today(10/31) did nothing, **the actual graph, the blue area** should start from 80 not 60.   If your today(10/31) did 30 capticy,the blue area should start from 50.

[image]

For a test you can set start date from 11/5~ 11/13 which have 9 days and 5 working days. However the chart should still start from 11/7, the first working day.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I don't understand, but my sprint contains four working days in a span of 6 days and the capacity of the team for each working day is 20, therefore the whole team capacity should be 80 in the beginning of the sprint, not 60. I think that is also reflected in the "Work details panel". I mention that I have also not moved any of the tasks to "In Progress" or "Completed" groups, if that helps. Therefore, my question remains the same: why does the graph starts from 60 instead of 80?

Comment: Sorry for the miss understanding, have update my reply. Please kindly review.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. So, total work is 80, this sprint starts today (31/10) and the chart takes 20 points (going to 60). The reason why it takes that amount is because the team is supposed to work today 20 points. If none of the tasks are marked as done by the end of today, the chart's available capacity should point to 80 at the end of today. If the team finishes 20 capacity points by the end of today, then the chart's available capacity should go to 40 at the end of today. Is that true?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant **remaining work**, instead of **available capacity** and **20 work points** instead of **20 capacity points**

Comment: Yes, you are right. A litter different, I'm not pretty sure. I think it's not by the end of today, it's tomorrow. If tomorrow  is working day, the remaining working will be 40 at that point in the chart.  This is just the ideal for a perfect situation in the chart.

Comment: Patrick I would like to thank you for your help, I feel that I understand the chart much better now.